# OpenCV not installing at the last stage on my Lubuntu system

Tags: command-line, software-installation, lubuntu, python, opencv

I was installing OpenCV on Lubuntu. I was on very last stage of installation. I'm not understanding what to do next.

Below is the error:

```
(cv) archit@ubuntu:~/opencv/build$ cd /usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.6
(cv) archit@ubuntu:/usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.6$ sudo mv cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so cv2.so
mv: cannot stat 'cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': No such file or directory
(cv) archit@ubuntu:/usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.6$ sudo mv cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so cv2.opencv3.4.4.so
mv: cannot stat 'cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you were following instructions, providing the instructions maybe helpful, or at least describing where *last stage of installation* was from (I don't see a `mv` step at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV)

Comment: post the output of `ls`

Comment: Check it in this path: `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/python-3.6/` instead